# Using named pipes to send keypresses to an interactive program

Tags: tty, fifo

I have a program, mpg123, which has an interactive mode that allows keyboard commands from stdin to do useful things such as control volume. I am trying to start up mpg123 so that it reads commands from a named pipe; that way I can have other programs interact with it.

In one terminal I do the following:

```
mkfifo pipe
tail -n1 -f pipe | mpg123 -vC /some/song.mp3
```

And in another terminal I do the following:

```
cat > pipe
-
```

Now, I was expecting that the `-` would be sent to the mpg123 program exactly the same as if I was sitting in that terminal smacking the <kbd>-</kbd> key, but that is not what happens. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `-C` causes mpg123 to read from the terminal, not from stdin. I see this, however, in my version of mpg123's man page:

```
-R, --remote
       Activate  generic  control interface.  mpg123 will then read and
       execute commands from stdin. Basic usage is ``load <filename> ''
       to  play some file and the obvious ``pause'', ``command.  ``jump
       <frame>'' will jump/seek to a given point (MPEG  frame  number).
       Issue ``help'' to get a full list of commands and syntax.
```

This may be what you are looking for; try `mpg123 -vR <pipe`. The
interaction in your example would become something like the following
(this sets the volume to 30%):

```
$ cat >pipe
load /some/song.mp3
volume 30
```

---

But then, what does `-C` do that `-R` doesn't that results in the
former mode failing to read from stdin when a named pipe, rather than
a terminal, is connected?

A quick look at the mpg123 source code indicates that it uses the
termios facilities to read keypresses from the terminal, using
`tcsetattr` to put it in the so-called "non-canonical mode", where
keypresses are transmitted to the reader without further processing
(in particular, without waiting for a complete line to have been
typed):

```
struct termios tio = *pattern;
(...)

tio.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
(...)

return tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&tio);
```

(This is the same as the [GNU libc code sample](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanon-Example.html).)

Then, in a loop, a function `get_key` is called, which uses `select`
to tell whether file descriptor 0 (stdin) has data available and, if
so, reads one byte from it (`read(0,val,1)`). But this still doesn't
explain why a terminal works but a pipe doesn't! The answer lies in
the terminal initialization code:

```
/* initialze terminal */
void term_init(void)
{
    debug("term_init");

    term_enable = 0;

    if(tcgetattr(0,&old_tio) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't get terminal attributes\n");
        return;
    }
    if(term_setup(&old_tio) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't set terminal attributes\n");
        return;
    }

    term_enable = 1;
}
```

Note that if either `tcgetattr` or `term_setup` fails, then
`term_enable` is set to 0. (The function to read keys from the terminal starts with `if(!term_enable) return 0;`.) And, indeed, when stdin isn't a terminal,
`tcgetattr` fails, the corresponding error message is printed, and the
keypress-handling code is skipped:

```
$ mpg123 -C ~/input.mp3 <pipe
(...)
Can't get terminal attributes
```

This explains why attempting to send commands by piping into `mpg123
-C` fails. That's a debatable choice by the implementors; presumably
by simply allowing `tcgetattr` / `tcsetattr` to fail (perhaps by using
a switch for that purpose), instead of disabling the keypress-handling
code handling, your attempt would have worked.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am still unclear how reading from the terminal is different from reading from stdin. Is there then a /dev/tty device somewhere that I can pipe commands to and have the "mpg123 -C" see that input? 

(I am trying to understand what is happening better so I can apply this to future, non-mpg123 problems)

Thanks!

Comment: stdin from a program is by default connected to the tty, but they don't have to be the same.  You can read/write to the tty as discussed http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138390/109842

Comment: @virosa: I will edit my answer to add more information. Long story short, mpg123 expects an actual terminal when `-C` is specified, and just ignores commands if something else (such as a pipe) is connected to stdin.